# Tag search broken today?

Tags: support, tag-search

I can search for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) on Stackoverflow, but searching for [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) doesn't give any results.

Likewise for other tags:

[image]

Comment: Precisely. Was just coming here to report the same. Have suggested an edit with evidence screenshot. I've been noting sluggish response times for the last few days anyways

Comment: We the C# users are taking over SO and soon SE will belong to us :)

Comment: @martijnpieters - I don't think it's fruitful to "just close" this as it is most clearly ***not*** an "exact duplicate". In fact this lists entirely different symptoms. Sysadmins will know that good problem analysis starts with **good reporting** of the symptoms. This way, seems to be a recipe to miss the symptom reports.

Comment: [2745](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windbg) results.

Comment: @Rob: okay ... 8 years later, it shows some results. That's great.

Comment: Thomas, it's in the Review Queue, being closed "no repo"; if it was still broken that shouldn't happen. I understand your frustration with the *answer* below.

Answer (score 5):

It breaks *every* Saturday.

Our crack team of ghostbusters are looking into why.

Until they figure it out, just consider this a reminder that it's Saturday and go eat some really sugary breakfast cereal.

Comment: Maybe the tags are Jewish? (Shomer Shabbat, you know :))

Comment: I can't judge whether this was fun, honest or whatever, so I can't accept it. I have not observed breaking every Saturday for 8 years now, which speaks against accepting this answer.