# Missing results from "newest" tag search

Tags: bug, tag-search

I'm missing results in the "newest" tag-search results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost+or+boost-phoenix+boost-spirit+boost-spirit-qi+boost-spirit-phoenix+boost-asio

[image]

It should include at least this question:

[image]

(all screenshots taken same exact moment ± 20s)

Possibly related:

- [Tag search broken today?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218322/tag-search-broken-today)
- [Very old questions in "Newest" in advanced tag search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240279/very-old-questions-in-newest-in-advanced-tag-search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a few `or` keywords in the search query if you are looking for posts with any of those tags. Your link leads to a search with the following search string:

```
[boost] or [boost-phoenix] [boost-spirit] [boost-spirit-qi] [boost-spirit-phoenix] [boost-asio]
```

This search will find posts that have the [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) tag, or **all of** the other tags you list in the rest of the search string.

To search for posts that contain any of the tags, use a search string with an `or` between each pair of tag names:

```
[boost] or [boost-phoenix] or [boost-spirit] or [boost-spirit-qi] or [boost-spirit-phoenix] or [boost-asio]
```

The result of this search includes the "missing" post highlighted in the question.

Comment: Aaaarg. I feel silly now. I must have at one time gotten used the wrong link from my browser history, and not noticed it in a loooong time. Thanks.